# Angular 8 Interface + Rest Response

Tags: angular, rest, interface

How can i display (resultData, correlationId, errors) in the component html?

1. Rest Json Response:

```
{
"correlationId": null,
"errors": [],
"resultData": [
[
{
"ssrefitem": 710,
"subservice": "232-Telefone Móvel",
"srefitem": 386,
"formcode": "SCaetano",
"useqty": true,
"useprice": true,
"taxratetype": "O3",
"usesupplier": true,
"rfqforcesupplier": false,
"usetype": false,
"useunit": false
},
{
"ssrefitem": 711,
"subservice": "233-Internet",
"srefitem": 386,
"formcode": "SCaetano",
"useqty": true,
"useprice": true,
"taxratetype": "O3",
"usesupplier": true,
"rfqforcesupplier": false,
"usetype": false,
"useunit": false
}
]
],
"valid": true
}
```

2. Interface for the Json Response ( servi.ts) . I used this https://app.quicktype.io for the "transformation".

```
 export interface SubServices {
  correlationId: null;
  errors: any[];
  resultData: Array<ResultDDD[]>;
  valid: boolean;
}

export interface ResultDDD {
  ssrefitem: number;
  subservice: string;
  srefitem: number;
  formcode: string;
  useqty: boolean;
  useprice: boolean;
  taxratetype: string;
  usesupplier: boolean;
  rfqforcesupplier: boolean;
  usetype: boolean;
  useunit: boolean;
}
```

3. My service (sot.service.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {SubServices} from './servi';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SotService {


  private sotUrl = 'cannot-give-the-real-one-but-the-response-is-in-the-1.';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getSubServices(): Observable<SubServices[]> {
    return this.http.get<SubServices[]>(this.sotUrl);
  }
}
```

4. My component (servi.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SotService} from '../sot.service';
import { SubServices} from '../servi';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sotlist',
  templateUrl: './sotlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sotlist.component.css']
})
export class SotlistComponent implements OnInit {

  todos: SubServices[];
  constructor( private sotService: SotService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSubServices();
  }

   getSubServices() {
     this.sotService.getSubServices()
       .subscribe(
         (data: SubServices[]) =>  {
           this.todos = data;
           console.log(this.todos);
         }
       );
  }
}
```

If i use something like this in the component.html

```
<div>

  <h3>Something Something</h3>


  <ul class="items">
    <li *ngFor="let res of todos.resultData">
      {{res}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It will give me :
1 . Something Something
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

2. The resultData use in ngFor in the console is : "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'resultData' of undefined"

Comment: Whats your console.log(this.todos) look like?

Comment: https://ibb.co/gt9fmTy

Answer (score 1):

In your response **resultData** is an array of array. So you need put following code in html.

```
<ul class="items">
    <li *ngFor="let res of todos.resultData[0]">
      {{res}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

And if you put only **{{res}}** it will give [object Object] in DOM. If you want to display whole object, you need to give pipe like **{{res | json }}**

Comment: The goal is , be using what's inside the resultData, displaying it.  If i use this (in html) <li *ngFor="let res of todos.resultData[0]">
      {{res.ssrefitem}}
    </li> It will give me the numbers(on the field ssrefitem) of the response. But on the console it will give me "SotlistComponent.html:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'resultData' of undefined" Why?

Answer (score 0):

In your service change your http call to:

```
return this.http.get<SubServices>(this.sotUrl);
```

Then in your component.ts change your getSubServices() method to this:

```
   getSubServices() {
     this.sotService.getSubServices()
       .subscribe(
         (data: SubServices) =>  {
           this.todos = data;
           console.log(this.todos);
         }
       );
  }
```

And your template:

```
<div>

  <h3>Something Something</h3>


  <ul class="items">
    <li *ngFor="let res of todos.resultData">
      {{res[0].subservice}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thks #tshoemake for the quick response. But on the console log it still gives me "Cannot read property 'resultData' of undefined". I use this in html :  <ul class="items">
    <li *ngFor="let res of todos.resultData[0]">
      {{res.ssrefitem}}
    </li>
  </ul>

Comment: You should change this *ngFor="let res of todos.resultData[0]" to this *ngFor="let res of todos.resultData" in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i changed the component to this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SotService} from '../sot.service';
import {ResultDDD, SubServices} from '../servi';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-sotlist',
  templateUrl: './sotlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sotlist.component.css']
})
export class SotlistComponent implements OnInit {

  todos: SubServices;
  public resul: ResultDDD[];
  constructor( private sotService: SotService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSubServices();
  }

   getSubServices() {
     this.sotService.getSubServices()
       .subscribe(
         (data: SubServices) =>  {
           this.todos = data;
           this.resul = this.todos.resultData[0];
           console.log(this.todos);
         }
       );
  }
}
```

Now on the html i use :

```
<div>

  <h3>Something Something</h3>


  <ul class="items">
    <li *ngFor="let res of resul">
      {{res.ssrefitem}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

No console errors and it display's correctly(and autocomplete on the html side)...
Thks tshoemake and Parth Dhankecha.